# JQuery ajax call receives invalid JSON, but no error handlers are called

Tags: jquery, ajax, simple-form

Informational question rather than an issue I need solved.  Couldn't find satisfactory answers elsewhere

I'm new to JQuery/JS, and I'm trying to test error handlers I have for an AJAX call to a rails backend.  I had a hell of a time getting the handlers to fire.

1. I tried letting the backend return a 500 and a stack trace, but the handlers didn't fire.  The console shows `VM26658:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0`.
2. I tried returning an empty response with a bad request status, but same error and behavior
3. I finally got the handlers to fire by returning an empty (but well formed) JSON response and a 400 status

So it seems that the Ajax error handlers don't fire when the response body cannot be parsed.  Is that correct?  If so that seems like a pretty substantial and unintuitive limitation of the handler logic.  If not, then how was I being stupid?

Thanks!

**Update with code**

In haml:

```
= simple_form_for @object, method: :put, url: setup_object_path, remote: true |f|
= f.input :some_input
= f.submit, class: 'js-submit'
```

In Coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'ajaxStart', startFunction
$(document).on 'ajaxError', errorFunction
$(document).on 'ajaxComplete', completeFunction
```

Result:
`startFunction` fires for all 3 cases, but `errorFunction` and `completeFunction` only fire for case #3

I also tried binding directly to `js-submit` with `ajax:error`, but had the same result

Comment: Parse error will trigger ajax error handler if `dataType` is set and/or correct Content Type header is set at server. Please show relevant code. This also assumes request isn't `jsonp`

Comment: updated with example code, thanks for the help

Comment: Afraid the haml references don't mean anything to me. Requests are all made in browser which only knows about what exists there

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.  Someone in my codebase had a document level binding to `ajax:error` that used `$.parseJSON`.  Anything that wasn't valid JSON was blowing up and stopping all other error handling.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the help